# Jquery AutoComplete Shows all list Instead of search result

Tags: jquery, json

I have jquery autocomplete with source of json like this :

```
   $(function () {
        $('body').delegate('input.city', 'focusin', function () {
            $(this).autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {

                    response($.map(JSON.parse(Cityjs), function (item) {
                        return { label: item.CityName, value: item.CityID };
                    }))},
                minLength: 3
            });
        });

    });

});
```

now when i search in box it shows all label results in list instead of auto complete. but when i use this method :

```
  var availableTags = ["...some content,some content..."];
    $('body').delegate('input.city', 'focusin', function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({ source: availableTags });
    });
```

it works. problem is i need ID of selected value from box.

**Cityjs** is json array that comes in model with pair of CityID and CityName.
Cityjs sample :

```
[{"CityID":7,"CityName":"AAA"},
{"CityID":6,"CityName":"BBB"},
{"CityID":5,"CityName":"VVV"}]
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on `ID of selected value from box`? Which ID?

Comment: @ShaunakD like item.CityID. the id of selected label